# Why 'history' doesn't output anything in tcsh when commands come from a file?

Tags: shell, tcsh

When we type "history" in tcsh, we can see a list of history commands, like this:

```
ubuntu:~> echo a
a
ubuntu:~> history
     1  9:20    echo a
     2  9:20    history
```

However, if we store in commands in a file "commands.txt"

```
echo a
history
```

And we redirect the content of this file into tcsh by

```
tcsh < commands.txt
```

What we can see is only:

```
a
```

Why does this happen? And why shell prompt isn't part of the output either?

BTW, it actually works for bash, you just need to turn on *history* option like this

```
set -o history
echo a
history
```

Answer (score 0):

well this maybe not a perfect answer to the question **why**. but at least it gives you some info, that don't use history command in a script.

in 
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html
search "history" you find:

> Note that within a script, the history mechanism is disabled.

in http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/histcommands.html you can find at the end of the page:

```
Unfortunately, the Bash history tools find no use in scripting.

#!/bin/bash
# history.sh
# A (vain) attempt to use the 'history' command in a script.

history                      # No output.

var=$(history); echo "$var"  # $var is empty.

# History commands disabled within a script.

bash$ ./history.sh (no output)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **history** command is a tcsh built-in so doesn't behave like a normal command. Per the "Csh Programming Considered Harmful" rant, section 2a says

> > You can't put [built-ins] together in many reasonable ways.

And I am not sure its even a *reasonable* way. And scripts don't print the command prompts.